# Cannot connect "button" to viewcontroller.h from a ViewController Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

[image: Picture 1]

I'm making an email app in which I first started off with embedding the ViewController in Navigation bar, after which I made a "FirstView" in which I added three buttons connecting them  to another ViewController for a detailed page. They worked fine, But when I tried to connect another button from the new viewcontroller to viewcontroller.h, It doesn't show any option to.

[image: Picture 2]

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Can you show how to added class name to UIViewController  in the place of Custom class in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your class_name to Identity Inspector in "Class" which is in upper right side corner and then try it, hope its work...!

Comment: Im sorrym didnt understand. Can you explain step by step? So sorry .-.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Xcode behaves a little "buggy". Some of the following might help:

- You should ensure that your project compiles without error, otherwise Xcode frequently doesn't recognize you D&D
- Drag from the code (the little cirle on the left hand side) into the xib
- If nothing else helps, restart Xcode

Comment: Which circle sir?

Comment: Take a look at the image you posted: Left of the `- (@IBAction) Send:(id)sender;` there is a litte non-filled circle. Drag&Drop this into the xib/storyboard onto the UI control you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check above image and just add your .swift class name in Identity Inspector

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things to resolve this:

1. Add your Class Name inside UIViewController in storyboard.

[image]

2. Make sure your Module also None. If not select Module field and click "delete".

**Note: If this works then perfect you can go ahead with this. If not then,**

3. cmd+shift+"k" clean the code and do once again 1st and 2nd step.
4. If still you faced same issue then Quit Xcode and reopen the project. This will work to resolve your issue.

Answer (score -2):

Simple Thing Is First You have To Check Whether You Try To Creating Action Inside Class Or Outside Class If You try to Create Action Outside The Class It Not Taking, If You Creating Inside The Class It Will Works
Even If You Are Creating Inside The Class Then Go For The Class Name gave The Class Name and Provide Storyboard Id Then Try It Will Definitely Works.
Thank you......